# React JS: problem in receiving cookie with axios, which is received from JWT Django

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, axios, jwt

First of all, I had made a POST APIView function using Django and added JWT token in it. This api is basically made for the login purpose. I can transfer all the details in it and recieve a cookie in return.

```
class LoginView(APIView):
   def post(self, request):
       email = request.data['email']
       password = request.data['password']

       user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

       if user is None:
           raise AuthenticationFailed('user not found')

       if not user.check_password(password):
           raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password')

       payload = {
           'id': user.id,
           'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
           'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
       }

       token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')

       response = Response()

       response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
       response.data = {
           'jwt': token
       }
       return response
```

I used POST request using axios in react js and trying to recieve cookie too with the help of "withCredentials: true" yet unable to get the cookie.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
    };

    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login ',
                withCredentials: true,
                data: {
                  email: this.state.email,
                  password: this.state.password
                }
              })
              .then(data => console.log(data));
    }


    handleChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({[name]:value})
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>LOGIN</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <div>
            <label>Email: </label>
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              value={this.state.email}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div>
            <label>Password: </label>
            <br />
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              value={this.state.password}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

[I am getting this issue in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K3ER.png)

Comment: Add **samesite = 'Lax'**.  `response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True,samesite = 'Lax')`

Comment: @Pradip this syntax is not working for me. ```axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login ',
                withCredentials: true,
                response.set-cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True,samesite = 'Lax'),
                data: {
                  email: this.state.email,
                  password: this.state.password
                }
              })``` and m recieving the error "  ',' expected."

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using axios. I had used fetch() which worked for me.

````
        event.preventDefault();
        
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/user/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email: this.state.email,
              password: this.state.password
            })
        });
        console.log(response)
    }```
````